# Issue of extra spaces when converting a pandas dataframe into a 1D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm converting a large pandas dataframe table into a 1D python list and removing the duplicate elements in this list as I need to. However, after converting into a list certain repetitions of some elements had an extra space before the beginning and because of that my 'remove duplicates' line wasn't efficient and it considered these as two different elements. Also, how can I remove an element from a list which is not a number (nan)? 
Sample Input :

```
        E1     E2     E3
0       A      B      NaN
1       A      C      NaN
2       A      B      C
...
300     X      B      C
```

This is the codelet I used to perform it: ('green' is the dataframe that contains the above table

```
MCS2=green.values.tolist()
MCS2=list(set(sum(MCS2,[])))
print(MCS2)
```

The expected output:

```
['A','B','C',....,'X']
```

But for some reason some of the 'A's have an extra space before them and they appear as ' A' and 'A' and hence are counted as two different elements even though they are the same. This is my output:

```
['A',' A','B','C',' C'....,'X']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) `whitespaces,`[`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and last convert [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print pd.DataFrame({'E1': {0: 'A ', 1: ' A', 2: 'A', 300: 'X'}, 
                    'E3': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: 'C', 300: 'C'}, 
                    'E2': {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'B', 300: 'B'}})

print df
     E1 E2   E3
0    A   B  NaN
1     A  C  NaN
2     A  B    C
300   X  B    C

print df.stack().str.strip().drop_duplicates().tolist()
['A', 'B', 'C', 'X']
```

Comment: It still has the same problem @jezrael . A few elements appear more than once in the new list just because of an extra space in the front.